# How can I format mathematical expressions using MathJax?

Tags: support, faq-proposed

Blatantly ripped off from [chem.SE](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/q/86), this post is meant to help people understand how to use MathJax formatting of mathematical expressions here on *Computational Science*.

Answer (score 2):

### Getting started with MathJax

On *Computational Science Stack Exchange*, we use [MathJax] to format mathematical expressions. MathJax is a tool that lets us display LaTeX expressions on a browser.

To use MathJax, enclose your mathematical expressions within single(`$...$`) or double(`$$...$$`) dollar signs. Single dollar signs make the expression *inline*, for example, `Let $x$ be a variable` gives:

> Let $x$ be a variable.

On the other hand, double dollar signs make the expression a block element. It gets its own line, and is slightly larger. For example, `The equation of motion is as follows: $$v=u+at$$ It is a SUVAT equation` gives:

> The equation of motion is as follows: $$v=u+at$$ It is a SUVAT equation

Note that the extra spaces in LaTeX do not render, use `\:` or `~` for a space.

---

### Basic MathJax

#### Superscripts and subscripts

You can denote superscripts via the `^` character, and subscripts via `_`. For example, `x^2` renders as $x^2$, `x_1` renders as $x_1$, and `x_1^3` renders as $x_1^3$.

If you want to include more than one character in the super/sub script, enclose it in curly braces (`{...}`).

For example, `x^10` renders as $x^10$, but `x^{10}` renders as $x^{10}$

#### Fractions and square roots

Fractions can be easily displayed using `\frac{..}{..}`. For example, `\frac{a+b^c}{de+f}` renders as $\frac{a+b^c}{de+f}$

Protip: You can exclude the braces for single-character numerators/denominators (if the first character is a letter, you need to use a space after `\frac`, though). For example `\frac12` renders as $\frac12$, and `\frac ab` renders as $\frac ab$

Square roots can be added in a similar manner, via `\sqrt{....}`. For example, `\sqrt{x+y}` renders as $\sqrt{x+y}$.

#### Greek letters

Greek letters can be added usung a backslash ('\'), followed by the name of the letter. Captialise the first letter of the name for greek capital letters.

Eg `\alpha \beta \gamma \Omega` renders as $\alpha \beta \gamma \Omega$.

Make sure that you put spaces after these if you are typing normal alphabet characters. Eg `e^{\pii}` gives an error, you need to use `e^{\pi i}` for $e^{\pi i}$.

Note that there are special commands `\varepsilon , \varsigma , \varrho , and \varpi` to distinguish between the lunate Greek letters ($\varepsilon \varsigma \varrho \varpi$ rather than $\epsilon \sigma \rho \pi$).

### Further reading

- [Wikipedia TeX help page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Help:Displaying_a_formula) (extremely useful as a reference, useless as a tutorial)
- [Harvard intro to TeX](http://www.math.harvard.edu/texman/)
- [LaTeX wikibook, Math section](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Mathematics)
- [LaTeX wikibook, Advanced Math section](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Advanced_Mathematics)

Thanks to [Manishearth](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/users/22/manishearth) for the [chem.SE answer](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/a/88) on which this is based.